# Reduce the size of the text in a TextArea as you type with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a really nice little function that reduces the text size inside some div's when they are displayed on the screen if they start overflowing.

```
$(function(){
    $('div.Body').each(function (index) {
        if ($('div.Body')[index].scrollHeight > 150) {
            $('div.Body')[index].style.fontSize = 'small';
            if ($('div.Body')[index].scrollHeight > 150) {
                $('div.Body')[index].style.fontSize = 'x-small';
                if ($('div.Body')[index].scrollHeight > 150) {
                    $('div.Body')[index].style.fontSize = 'xx-small';
                }
            }
        }
    });
})
```

I wanted to use the same/similar function to do the same while the users are typing the text into a textArea when they are submitting the text, but the textArea doesn't seem to have a function for scrollHeight:

```
$(function() {
    window.status = $('.TextAreaClass').scrollHeight;
});
```

This function just returns undefined.

How can I accomplish this in a textArea?

Comment: _Please_ save `$('div.Body')[index]` to a temporary variable (Cache it). What you're doing is highly inefficient. Or better yet, simply use `this`, as that will be `$('div.Body')[index]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scrollHeight` is a native javascript method, not a jQuery one so you will need to do the following to get the `scrollHeight` of the `textarea`:

```
window.status = $('.TextAreaClass')[0].scrollHeight;
```

Note the `[0]` which returns the first element in the jQuery object, which is the native DOM element. Also, you should really be caching the selected element in your current code to make it perform better. Try this:

```
$('div.Body').each(function (index) {
    var div = $('div.Body')[index];
    if (div.scrollHeight > 150) {
        div.style.fontSize = 'small';
        if (div.scrollHeight > 150) {
            div.style.fontSize = 'x-small';
            if (div.scrollHeight > 150) {
                div.style.fontSize = 'xx-small';
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Finally, the logic of that code seems flawed, as all the conditions are checking `> 150`?

Comment: The test is the same because it expects the previous line to have changed the height.

Comment: The `var div` is ok but you could also just use the second parameter of `.each( function( index, element )` and you would have access to `element` without needing to assign a the element to a variable at each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `this`, instead of getting `$('div.Body')[index]` for each iteration of the loop:

```
$('div.Body').each(function () { // Remove the redundant parameter
    if (this.scrollHeight > 150) {
        this.style.fontSize = 'small';
        if (this.scrollHeight > 150) {
            this.style.fontSize = 'x-small';
            if (this.scrollHeight > 150) {
                this.style.fontSize = 'xx-small';
            }
        }
    }
});
```

In the `.each`, `this` refers to `$('div.Body')[index]`.

And, like Rory said, `$('.TextAreaClass')` returns a jQuery object. You'll probably want to use `$('.TextAreaClass')[0];` to access the first DOM element in that object.

Comment: In the `each()` `this` will refer to `$('div.Body')`, *not* `$('div.Body')[index]`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Run `$('div').each(function(){console.log(this)});` on this page. I tested this code, and saw all div's logged.

Comment: Once again, incorrect. [RTFM](http://api.jquery.com/each/#example-0) before trying to invalidate my answer. Or at least, test your claims.

Comment: Sorry dude. My bad. Not having a good morning :( In my defence I did try to test it in a fiddle, but it seems to be down this morning. I've +1'd your answer.

Comment: [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net) seems to be working fine here. Also, you can always run your code in the dev console (F12). Sorry for the snark :P

Comment: No problem, I do the same when some moron tries to argue with my answers... been a while since I was the moron LOL

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you were almost correct, the second parameter in the `each( function( index , element )` is the element itself, not the jQuery object